# anchors to horizontal panels on another page with mbScrollable

Tags: jquery

I have a css menu on all my pages and a .mbScrollable script running on one page with 10 scrollable horizontal panels.  Earlier I was showed how to use named anchors to go right to a given panel from the css menu on that page.

My question is how do I do it from other pages?  When I use the menu from other pages the new "onclick" code I added only takes me to the page where the anchors are not the specific anchor.

Comment: Is the hash being set? So, /new_page#somediv

Comment: I second the above answer

Comment: <a href="about_ahds.html#ap" onclick="$('#myScroll').goToPage(2); return false;">